# Pandas: compare two columns values against a nested dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I was reading a lot but I couldn't figure out how can I do this. I have a df with two columnns: `data` and `fold`, and a nested dictionary called `dicDataFolds` with `data` as keys and `fold` as key of each dictionary like this:

```
dicDataFolds =  {'data1': {1: 111936, 2: 111928, 3: 111821, 4: 111852, 5: 111882},
                 'data2': {1: 1566460, 2: 1566434, 3: 1566245, 4: 1566502, 5: 1566550},
                 'data3': {1: 292478, 2: 316757, 3: 316671, 4: 292265, 5: 316018},
                  ...
                  }
```

I would like to access to the dictionary in order to obtain the value pointed by the 'data' and 'fold' columns values, and store it in a new column.

Any suggestions?

Comment: try converting dict to df and then work with df: ```df=pf.DataFrame(dicDataFolds)```

Comment: I've followed your suggestion creating a `dfdic` from my dictionary, but I don't know how to access using both columns values: I've tried this `dfdic[df['data']][df['fold']]` but it doesnt work

Comment: Next tou can merge your two dataframes and get the result you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Write a function that

  - takes a Series as an argument;
  - extracts the `data` and `fold` values from that Series;
  - accesses the dictionary with those values;
  - and returns the result.
- apply the function along axis 1 of `dataframe[['data','fold']]`
- assign the return value from that *application* to a new column of the DataFrame

Comment: Thank you, I've solved in a similar way you answered but I thought there will be something more straightfoward.